# The study of Procedure Words

Tags: terminology, study-of-terms

I want to do a research about [prowords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedure_word) - procedure words - those are used in army to communicate. In what field of linguistics I will find the study about procedure words? Is it in morphology, sociolinguistics, psycholinguistics, or something else?

Comment: Of the ones you mentioned, more likely sociolinguistics. More specifically, pragmatics, conversation analysis, perhaps discourse analysis.

Comment: I wouldn't call such things "prowords" when talking to linguists, they'd probably think you're referring to [pro-forms](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-form).

Answer (score 1):

You may find some study of such phenomena in *Applied linguistics* where *terminology* (i.e., study of terms), *translation studies* and *controlled languages* are subjects.